# List to C# controller from angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to send this list to a C# MVC controller method

```
        getList: function (accesslist, amount) 
        {
            return $http.get('/Theme/GetList', 
            {
                params: 
                {
                    accesslist: accesslist,
                    amount: amount
                }
            })
        },
```

The Controller looks like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetList(IEnumerable<ViewModel> accesslist, double Amount)
```

The list doesn't is transformed to a string, and it don't hit the controller method.

The works with $resource but not with $http.get

What is wrong with that? Can I do this? I need the list to create another list.

Comment: You don't use a post instead of a get if you have parameters to send ?

Comment: I need a list to be returned

Answer (score 0):

You have first to declare the variable and use it in params

```
getList: function (accesslist, amount) {
       var accesslist = accesslist;
       var amount = amount;
        return $http.get('/Theme/GetList', {
            params: {
                accesslist: accesslist,
                amount: amount
            }
        })
    },
```

Comment: I still get a 404 (Not Found)

Comment: your answer makes no sense. It still is same as above